# Sequencia numérica recursiva em Java

Tags: java, recursão

Estou precisando fazer uma sequência numérica em modo recursivo que, após chegar no n número (5, no exemplo), começa a fazer a sequencia inversa.

Exemplo:

> 1234554321

Já fiz o que faz a sequência normal, agora resta o que inverta os números. Podem me ajudar?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner read = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Sequencia numerica...\n");
        int sequencia = nSequencia(1);
    }

    static int nSequencia(int iSequencia) {
        System.out.print(iSequencia);
        if(iSequencia >= 5){
            return 1;
        }
        else{
            return nSequencia(iSequencia + 1);
        }
    }  
}
```

Comment: Isso parece enunciado mal feito, ou então problema ruim para recursão. Tem certeza que sempre deve ir até 5? então porque está falando em `n`?

Comment: Você poderia utilizar de ponteiros para ordenar essa sua lista, assim tornando um código mais dinâmico e não tão estático como o que você postou